# How to map a one-many relationship that has an attribute (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entities O and D with a one to many relationship from O (one) to D (many). The relationship itself has an attribute - count.

What is the best way to model this using hibernate?

What I have currently is another entity OD representing the relationship. It has its own artificial key

The abbreviated version of the entities is as below

```
@Entity
class O {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "o")
    private Set<OD> ods;
}

@Entity
class OD {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private O o;

    // This is uni-directional reln
    @OneToOne
    private D d;

    private int count;
}
```

Is this the best way? I do not like the fact that the relationship has its own id, but is there a better way to model this relationship?

Comment: why do you need OD entity, since you already have `@OneToMany` relation between O and D? If you want to count D entities just count set elements in O entity.

Comment: Set elements would represent data records. Implies redundancy and duplication @over9k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model the `OD` as `@Embeddable`, and change the owning side from `@OneToMany` to `@ElementCollection` e.g.

```
@Entity
public class O {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable( name = "OD")
    private Set<OD> ods;
}

@Embeddable
public class OD {

    // This is uni-directional reln
    @OneToOne
    private D d;

    private int count;
}
```

The `DDL` statements would be almost the same with the distinction that the life-cycle of the OD would always be dependent on the life of its parent object, and would not hold an identity of its own